# Custom UITableViewCell disappearing after scrolled past top

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell loaded from a nib file. Everything works fine until I scroll down past the last cell such that the table view has to bounce back when I let go.

Then, the cells towards the top of the list are blank and remain blank until I manually refresh the table view.

Image of issue: [iPhone Screenshot][1]

Here is my cell for row code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TimeEntryCellIdentifier";

TimeEntryCell *cell = (TimeEntryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimeEntryCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id oneObject in nib) {
        if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[TimeEntryCell class]]) {
            cell = (TimeEntryCell *) oneObject;
        }
    }
}

TimeEntry *aTimeEntry = [appDelegate.timeEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.clientName.text = aTimeEntry.ClientName;
cell.category.text = aTimeEntry.CategoryName;
cell.hours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aTimeEntry.Hours];

[TimeEntry release];

return cell;
}
```

Any ideas?

[1]: http://dl.nvthost.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Screen shot 2011-02-18 at 2.46.42 PM.png

[1]: http://dl.nvthost.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Screen shot 2011-02-18 at 2.46.42 PM.png

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be doing the

```
[TimeEntry release];
```

there on the next to last line.  You didn't allocate it in that method, just pulled a reference from the delegate.  The retain count is probably zero at that point.  When iOS starts releasing memory that TimeEntry will be dealloc'd.

Comment: That was put in there as part of the debugging process. I removed it and still have the same issue.

Comment: Now I'm stumped.  Went and looked at some code that I have that does this and one difference was in testing the output of the nib load. 'if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] )' was used rather than texting for the extended UITableViewCell class.  There may be memory issues elsewhere that are manifesting itself at this point in the app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out the be the view hierarchy in IB. Even though I put a view in the cell and then dragged UILabels onto the view, they ended up on the same level as the view. After I moved the UILabels under the view it appears to be working.